# How can I get the UIButton in AVPlayerViewController in Webview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton, ios11

I wanted to change the action for these `UIButton`, but it is in `AVPlayerViewController` in `WKWebView`.

[image]

And now, my idea is that to fetch the window by `NSNotification` about `UIWindowDidBecomeVisibleNotification` and to find the sub views of this window to achieve all buttons. But I can't succeed.

```
// viewDidLoad
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(windowDidBecomeActive:)
                                                 name:UIWindowDidBecomeVisibleNotification
                                               object:nil];

- (void)windowDidBecomeActive:(NSNotification *)notification {

    UIWindow *thisWindow = (UIWindow *)notification.object;
    // To achieve
}
```

And I try to add my custom view in this window to intercepted this tap gesture by `hitTest`. And the view is `nil`. But this action is actually able to perform. (WTF *(:зゝ∠)* .......

```
class RemoteFunctionAVPlayerView: UIView {
    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        let view = super.hitTest(point, with: event) // nil
        return view
    }
}
```

And how can I get the button and change its click action?